# Как поменять расположение импортируемого класса с com.example на пакет проекта

Tags: android, kotlin, импорт, package

Пакет, в котором находится мой поект выглядит следующим образом:

```
package com.semenovnikolay...
```

Однако некоторые импорты выглядят так:

```
import com.example.pharmacy_version2.R
import com.example.pharmacy_version2.databinding.MedicinesItemBinding
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это авто-сгенерированные классы, они помещаются в пакет, указанный в манифесте атрибутом `package`:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pharmacy_version2">
```

Либо по-новому в gradle скрипте свойством `namespace`:

```
android {
    namespace "com.example.pharmacy_version2"
    ...
}
```

Собственно их нужно изменить, выполнить синхронизацию и ребилд.
После ручками исправить везде их импорты.